# How does hard disk space allocation work in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Let's say I have 4 identical servers with 300GB hard drive space and a replication factor of 2 (so basically 2 300GB nodes, each replicated on another physical machine with 300GB space), how does the space allocation work across these nodes?

For instance, imagine 300GB on Node 1 and 2 (node 2 being the replica of 1) is completely used by cassandra and another application which also uses disk space, but the second set (nodes 3 and 4) have some free disk space since they're only running Cassandra and nothing else. Would Cassandra store new entries on these nodes instead given the fact the first 2 nodes are out of disk space, or would it blow up?

Broadening the situation across multiple servers in a rack, would Cassandra intelligently manage disk space requirements and put the data on nodes with more free storage space? Similarly, would it be able to work with servers with varying storage spaces? (some 600GB, some 300GB, etc.).

Many thanks,

Comment: Not a programming question. Server configuration/operation is offtopic for this site. Try the DBA site instead.

Comment: It's more a question with how Cassandra internally stores and manages its diskspace. In my opinion, it's more programming related than DBA related. I don't envisage anyone on ServerFaults would be able to answer this question since it's dealing with internals of Cassandra operation and not how it's configured.

Comment: no, it's server configuration. every DBMS worth its salt allows you configure disk space allocation strategies to some extent or another. since it's a configurable option, there's no point in asking what cassandra uses internally, because it's under user control anyways.

Comment: Not sure if you've worked with Cassandra before, but I don't believe there's an option to configure the disk space allocation using user specified configuration in Cassandra. The only 2 options I'm able to see are to configure where the data-log and the commit-log will go. Those 2 are configured per node and refer to folders and not sizes. If there's such a config (to let Cassandra know how much disk space is available per node), it's not documented here  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra does not allocate data by available space. It places data on nodes based on the hash of their *Partition Key*. Because of this there can be no intelligent live balancing of where data should go.

To do approximate balancing you can change the size of the token ranges a particular node is responsible for (no-vnodes) or adjust the number of vnodes. This all needs to be done manually.

Changes in the Cassandra.yaml

Example Vnodes:

```
Node 1: num_token: 128
Node 2: num_token: 128
Node 3: num_token: 256
Node 4: num_token: 256
```

Example Non-Vnodes (given a full range = 100):

```
Node1: initial_token: 15
Node2: initial_token: 30
Node3: initial_token: 65
Node4: initial_token: 100
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll try to figure out what these values exactly mean and set them up accordingly.

Comment: Be sure to check out http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html
As a reference for the various Cassandra Yaml settings